# How long does Image.prefetch actually cache the image?

Tags: image, caching, react-native, prefetch

When testing on the iOS Simulator I seem to be downloading the image every time the app is opened. Is this the intended behavior?

The three images are prefetched initially, and the cache is used whenever I reference that URI but as soon as I reload the app everything seems to reset.

Here are some snippets of how I'm using it inside my component.

```
prefetchImages(images) {
  let p = [];

  images.map((url) => {
    p.push(Image.prefetch(url).then(() => {
      console.log('image prefetched:', url);
    }));
  });

  return Promise.all(p);
}

this.prefetchImages([
  'http://domain.com/myimg1.jpg',
  'http://domain.com/myimg2.jpg'
])).then((a) => {
  console.log('all images have been prefetched');
});
```

I would just like to know whether or not the images are meant to be cached even after the app is relaunched.

Ideally I'd like to download some assets once and have them persist to disk for a sensible period.

Does `Image.prefetch` check HTTP Status Codes behind the scenes? I'm not sure how to log network requests through the simulator to see. I wonder if it receives a `304 Not Modified` when the app is relaunched, or whether it's always `200`. Any help appreciated.